# Рукавица - рука, перчатка - перст, варежка - ?

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова **варежка**?
Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, на Украине все называется "рукавицей" (или "рукавичкой"), у нас слова "варежка" вообще нет.

Comment: В **литературном** варианте укр.языка -- нет. Т.е. диктор по ТВ так не скажет, а в разговорном -- говорят и *варежка* и *перчатка*.

Если считать, что *варежка* от слова *варяг* (см. ответы ниже), то древний путь из варяг в греки был через Киев.

Comment: А  начинался  в  Ладоге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут интересно.
Слово "варежка" — это сокращенный вариант выражения "варяжская рукавица". Видимо, до прихода варягов славяне не знали такой формы одежды, вот и назвали так.

Comment: Я думаю, что дело в материале. До варягов рукавицы было кожаными и меховыми. Варежка предполагала шерсть, первоначально, видимо буйволов и бизонов.

Answer (score 2):

Если,  варежка  -  варяжская  рукавица,  то  это  не  значит,  что  она  сильно  отличалась  от  обычной.  Скорее  всего  это  слово  бытовало  в  северных  говорах,  а  в  южных  -  рукавица.  В  московских  говорах  использовали  оба  слова.  Может  первоначально  варежка  и  отличалась  от  рукавицы  по  материалу  или  крою.

Comment: Есть забавное слово из западно-украинских говоров -- ногавицы (ногавицi). Штаны значит :-). Их же на ноги надевают.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо версии "варяжской" Крылова, которая выглядит весьма убедительной, есть еще объяснение от корня "вар", только не "защитной" этимологии (кажется, она тоже варяжская), а вполне себе русская, от "варить".

Варежки - в отличие от рукавиц - были шерстяными. Технологию обработки шерсти завезли на Русь те же варяги. И технология эта включала непременную варку шерсти.

Недостоверно в целом, но посылки достаточно основательны.
Сравните: валенки - от валять, "сапоги" предположительно - от "сапать" (сопеть), "вареги"/"вАренки" - от варить. От "варенок" недалеко и но варежек.

Comment: В  общем,  тому,  что  я  написал  это  не  противоречит.  Но  шерсть  варили,  вероятно,  с  целью  обезжиривания.  И  славяне  должны  были  бы  это  знать.  Это  стандартный  этап  в  обработке  шерсти.  А ваш  источник  обсновал  варяжское  происхождение  такой  технологии.  Вы  же  тоже  нашли  это  не  совсем  достоверным.

Comment: В литературе  я  встречал  ещё  одно  объяснение  происхождения  варежек  или  варег  от  корня  вар.  Объяснялось  как  спецодежда  солеваров,  для  защиты  рук  от  брызг  и  пара  кипящего  рассола.